# How to test migrations faster in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have tried writing [a test on specific migration files](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2016/02/02/writing-unit-tests-django-migrations/). Basically I wanted to test the current state of the database and data between a pair of migrations. I used `MigrationExecutor` as follows:

```
executor = MigrationExecutor(connection)
old_apps = executor.loader.project_state(self.migrate_from).apps
executor.migrate(self.migrate_from)
# do something here
executor.migrate(self.migrate_to)
```

We have so many migration files in the project, so running all of them with unit tests takes a lot of time. Usually, I would set the migration modules to `None` in the a `settings_test.py`:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES: {
    'my_app': None
}
```

With this setting, the test would run really fast. The problem is that the migration files to test (`self.migrate_from` and `self.migrate_to`) can no longer be found:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Node ('poleluxe', '0090_auto_previous_migration') not a valid node
```

So I had to include the migration modules again in the test.

Is there a way to include migration files without running all them? In my case, I want to skip all the migrations from `0001` to `0089` and run only `0090` (as `self.migration_from`) and `0091` (as `self.migrate_to`).

I'm thinking of squashing the first 89 migrations and put the result in a separate folder together with `0090` and `0091`, then refer to that migration folder in the test. However, I'm not sure if this would be a great solution.

Comment: have you read https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2016/02/02/writing-unit-tests-django-migrations/ for this kind of testing?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I've already included that one in the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand so far, please guide me if I'm not correct.

**The problem**

1. [Migration test code](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2016/02/02/writing-unit-tests-django-migrations/) needs migration being applied.
2. Django starts earlier than any other process such as `@override_setting` and `setUpClass()`

**The Solution**

Override `MIGRATION_MODULES` setting at the very beginning of TestClass even when TestClass was not fully initialized because that's where I only found the right point.

With this way, not only you can disable all migration to speed up when you run your tests but also you can test migration files.

1. Disable all migration from `settings.py`.

   ```
   MIGRATION_MODULES = {app: None for app in INSTALLED_APPS}
   ```
2. (Optional) Remove `--nomigrations` options from pytest setting if you use pytest-django.
3. Override 'MIGRATION_MODULES' setting and set it back after test.

   ```
   class TestMigrations(TestCase):
       origin_modules = getattr(settings, 'MIGRATION_MODULES', {})
       setattr(settings, 'MIGRATION_MODULES', {})    

       ...

       @classmethod
       def tearDownClass(cls):
           setattr(settings, 'MIGRATION_MODULES', cls.origin_modules)
           super().tearDownClass()
   ```

**Trial Info**

1. `@override_setting` on TestClass or TestMethod **Not working** because Django starts and run migration earlier than `@override_setting` decoration
2. pytest-django with `--nomigrations` **Not working** not so sure but my workaround is that disable migrations from Django setting instead of pytest-django